# What will happen if I call a method on an iterator pointing to an empty element of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Alright, so here's the deal: I have a vector of size 0 that will be filled with pointers (With vector::push_back) and at some point in my program, I need to deallocate the elements of the vector and clear the vector itself.

The problem is that later I'll need to fill the vector with some new pointers and I'm worried of what will happen if the amount of pointers is smaller than the actual size of the vector (After I cleared it) and I call a method on an iterator pointing to one of those empty elements at the end of the array.

Will it be undefined behavior, if not, what will happen?

Comment: Existing iterators will be invalidated by `clear()`. But if you create a new iterator after calling `clear()` and then pushing new elements into the vector the new iterator will work fine. The *capacity* of the vector may remain reserved, but this doesn't affect the *size*

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for `std::vector::clear` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/):

> **Iterator validity**
>
> All iterators, pointers and references related to this container are invalidated.

You'll find this particular documentation site includes notes (titled 'Iterator validity') on how container operations affect validity of iterators pointing to elements in the container.

Comment: Alright, so should I simply shrink the vector with the swap trick?

Comment: `std::vector::clear` will reduce the size of the vector to 0. You needn't worry about accessing 'empty' elements, but do not attempt to use iterators to elements of the `std::vector` that existed before the call to `std::vector::clear`.

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I needed to know. I was worried that I would run into a problem when trying to iterate through the cleared vector with new iterators.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing `size` and `capacity`. When you add elements to your vector, you are increasing vector size, and if size exceeds capacity the underlying buffer will grow to get sufficient capacity.

Now, when you `clear` a vector, the vector size goes down to 0. The capacity does not necessarily go down, but usually you don't care as what is important for your algorithms is the size. Vector's `end` and obviously `size()` are determined by the size, not by the capacity.

Finally, if you would like to get capacity back to the size when you are removing elements, since C++11 there is [shrink_to_fit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/).

Comment: Indeed, I was mixing them. I was unsure if I could potentially iterate through some garbage in the cleared vector.

Comment: As long as you are ending your iteration with `it != end()` or `i < size()`, or using a range-for as `for (auto x : v)`, this will not happen. Technically, nothing prevents you from reading the "garbage" by iterating up to `capacity()` if you do it wrong, so just make sure you understand which methods are about size and which are about capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Using an iterator which has been invalidated causes undefined behaviour.

You have to design your code in such a way that you do not store any iterators in one place, whilst clearing the vector (or doing pretty much anything else to the vector for that matter) in another.

If you do want to store iterators then `vector` is probably not a good container choice; but for all containers , clearing them must of course invalidate any iterator to an element.